# Why not just use log for regression if it improves r-squared?

Tags: regression, model, r-squared, intuition, logarithm

theoretical question here:

Say I have a model, $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + u$

and it gives an $R^2$ of 0.02

Suppose, I re-estimate the model with $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1\log(x) + u$

which gives an $R^2$ of 0.03 (arbitrarily greater)

My intuition is that this **doesn't** suggest I should necessarily use log instead of level form, but I can't properly explain why. Any ideas?

Comment: Presumably you mean $\beta_1 x_1$ and $\beta_1\log(x_1)$?

Comment: haha yes, sorry about that - fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Sure. You can even use [more general transformations of the variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_model). The important thing (as hinted in the wiki article) is to take over fitting into account.

Comment: Unless the relationship between the y and x values is perfectly linear there will always be transformations of $x$ that have higher $R^2$. But choosing transformations in order to maximize $R^2$ will have neither explanatory value  nor predictive power.

Comment: @Glen_b that was my intuition as well, but is there some statistical/more concrete reason? or is it just the fact that not every transformation is justified, necessarily?

Comment: Consider the set of transformed $x$ variates across transformations one might contemplate as a (potentially infinite) class of potential regressors. In that context, read chapter 4 of Harrell's *Regression Modelling Strategies*, or some of the many posts on the problems associated with variable selection to optimize some within-sample criterion (such as $R^2$) to be found here on CV.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that instead of the logarithm you plugged a polynomial of $n-1$ degree, where $n$ is the number of observations, say this one:
$$z(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( \prod_{\stackrel{\!1\leq j\leq n}{j\neq i}}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right ) y_i $$

Now your model becomes:
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_zz(x) + u$$

Your $R^2$ will become 1. However, this clearly doesn't mean that you should go with this model. For the same reason, you can't go with $\ln x$ just because $R^2$ is higher.